# How to use Cox proportional hazards model in interval-censored data with time-dependent variables?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

The question is self-explanatory. I have survival data (n=156) which, in about half of the observations, is right-censored or interval-censored. I'm am using R to do the analysis and I know I can use intcox() and survfit() to deal with interval-censored data. But, in my point of view, none of this functions can deal with time-dependent variables.
To deal with time-dependent variables without interval-censored data, I am using coxph().

How can I analyse this type of data (if it is possible)?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find an answer?